# Convert rows to columns in SQL

Tags: pivot, database-agnostic

I'm looking for a query to achieve the following:

Current table format

```
user_id   meta_key    meta_value
-------   --------    ----------
1         address1    abc street
1         city        austin
1         state       TX
```

Desired output

```
user_id   address1    city         state
-------   --------    ----------   -----
1         abc street  austin       TX
```

Comment: What DBMS is this for?  [tag:sql] is *not* the same as [tag:sql-server]

Comment: [This answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116963/10832) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

To transpose the EAV table to the relational representation you can `JOIN` the source table with itself several times:

```
SELECT a.user_id    AS user_id
     , a.meta_value AS address1
     , b.meta_value AS city
     , c.meta_value AS state
  FROM table AS a
  JOIN table AS b  ON b.user_id = a.user_id  
                  AND a.meta_key = 'address1' -- an anchor to restrict the result size
                  AND b.meta_key = 'city'     -- first attribute appended
  JOIN table AS c  ON c.user_id = a.user_id
                  AND c.meta_key = 'state'    -- append the next attribute

-- JOIN table AS d  ON d.user_id = a.user_id
--                 AND d.meta_key = 'someattr'-- append the next attribute...
-- . . . ditto . . . 
;
```

This is not very handy approach if your EAV table contains lot of attributes for each entity but it can be automated by adding sequential `JOIN`s.

Answer (score -2):

In oracle you could write it this way

```
select u.user_id, 
       a.meta_value as address, 
       c.meta_value as city, 
       s.meta_value as state 
from (select unique user_id from current_table) u,
     current_table a,
     current_table c,
     current_table s 
where u.user_id = a.user_id   
  and a.meta_key = 'address1'   
  and u.user_id = c.user_id   
  and c.meta_key = 'city'   
  and u.user_id = s.user_id   
  and s.meta_key = 'state';
```

Comment: I would encourage you not to post [code-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/194636). They may solve the problem, but they don't often have much lasting teaching value. You can [edit] your answer to improve that aspect; see [answer].